# graphql query with different output

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

I have an api with an endpoint which can takes different query parameters.
`/toto?number=&shipments.tracking_number=&customer.email=`. The thing is that to get the query, I'm using only one input on the frontend and depending on that input, I have to fill the corresponding query parameter. But, depending on the query the user is passing, the JSON I receive in response is different. For example if he provides his email, the `duplicates` field won't be present in the response or if he provides a `tracking number`, the `total` won't be there either. Is there a way to make a query that is dynamic to handle if a field is in the response or not ?

```js
export const GET_ORDER = gql`
  query GetOrder($query: String!) {
    getOrder(query: $query) {
      id
      tokenValue
      number
      total
      duplicates
      shippingTotal
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two subtypes as an example using [unions and interfaces](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/), you can easily extend to additional ones.

In your *typeDefs*:

```
interface CoreOrder {
  id: ID!
  tokenValue: String!
  number: Int!
  shippingTotal: Float!
}

Type Order1 implements CoreOrder {
  id: ID!
  tokenValue: String!
  number: Int!
  shippingTotal: Float!
  total: Float!
}

Type Order2 implements CoreOrder {
  id: ID!
  tokenValue: String!
  number: Int!
  shippingTotal: Float!
  duplicates: Int!
}

union Order = Order1 | Order 2
```

Now your query can be defined to return whichever fields are appropriate:

```
query GetOrder($query: String!) {
  getOrder(query: $query) {
    __typename
    id
    tokenValue
    number
    shippingTotal
    ... on Order1 {
      total
    }
    ... on Order2 {
      duplicates
    }
  }
}
```

You'll need to implement:

1. a `__resolveType` [resolver](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/#resolving-a-union) that figures out what type your query is returning
2. resolvers for `CoreOrder` to handle those 4 fields
3. an `Order1` resolver for the `total` field
4. an `Order2` resolver for the `duplicates` field

Your GraphQL server will then figure out which resolvers to call and in what order and package up the results for your client.